# retriew all data of product list magento api

Tags: php, magento, soap

how to get all data?

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list');

var_dump($result);
```

its show my array:

```
    array
  0 =>
    array
      'product_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sku' => string 'n2610' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'Nokia 2610 Phone' (length=16)
      'set' => string '4' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'simple' (length=6)
      'category_ids' =>
        array
          0 => string '4' (length=1)
  1 =>
    array
      'product_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'sku' => string 'b8100' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'BlackBerry 8100 Pearl' (length=21)
      'set' => string '4' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'simple' (length=6)
      'category_ids' =>
        array
          0 => string '4' (length=1)
```

but i need get another data of products list like description, image, weight and etc.

thank u

Answer (score 0):

save new apiuser and apikey in your magento and use in following code.

```
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url with your url
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary 

    $result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
    var_dump($result);
```

Use above code will work.